# Ubuntu - Mysql, I have two permissions for a user, how do I delete one?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, apache2

I am running into the problem that my PHP scripts won't execute mysql insert queries, only read(select). I came down to the conclusion that it might be because of the permissions the user had, and I found two GRANT permissions under the user, so I think that's the reason.

[image]

I want the user to have all privileges, or at least read and write. How do I remove the first grant ?

I have tried this:

[image]

I learned that you can't revoke the USAGE permission. Instead you have to drop user, and create it on new I guess.

Comment: Did you try googling that? I doubt it.

Comment: Haha I actually did, couldn't find anything that showed it, but maybe that's just me searching for the wrong stuff. I'm new to all this ubuntu stuff and terminal..

Comment: Sorry if I'm coming off like a smart-ass but I entered "mysql delete user p" and then it autocompleted to privileges and the second entry was the link I posted as answer below...

Comment: I'll take a look on that search, thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/remove-permissions-for-a-mysql-user-on-linux-via-command-line/

> REVOKE permission ON database.table FROM 'user'@'localhost';

Please just google it before asking questions. It's what I do to find these answers...

Comment: I'm trying this: REVOKE permission ON star.star TO 'user'@'localhost'; but not working (Star is * but wouldn't show)

Comment: You have to enter the granted permission instead of "permission". Like `REVOKE usage ON *.* TO <here your user>`

Comment: Gives me syntax error: Tried it many different ways, but here's one: REVOKE usage ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost'; What's wrong?

Comment: Added a new screenshot to the answer.

Comment: By the way, I'm not really sure what the exact syntax error was anymore, since it came up with some -> shit I couldn't get out from.. so had to reopen the terminal.